# Filter out all data frames which don't have the column Z in a list of data frames?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a list of six data frames, from which 5/6 data frames have a column "Z". To proceed with my script, I need to remove the data frame which doesn't have column Z, so I tried the following code:

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  if(!("Z" %in% colnames(df[[i]])))
  {
    df[[i]] = NULL
  }
}
```

This seem'd to actually do the job (it removed the one data frame from the list, which didn't have the column Z), BUT however I still got a message "Error in df[[i]] : subscript out of bounds". Why is that, and how could I get around the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your list of 6 dataframes, you can do this:

```
df <- df[sapply(df, \(i) "Z" %in% colnames(i))]
```

The reason you get the error is that your loop will reduce the length of `df`, such that `i` will eventually be beyond the (new) length of df. There will be no error if the only frame in `df` without column `Z` is the last frame.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well! However, I was curious on why do we need the backslash before (i)? What does it stand for..?

Comment: this is a shortcut in R version >=4.1.0; if you have an earlier version you can use `function(i)` in place of `\(i)`

Answer (score 4):

The base `Filter` function works well here:

```
df <- Filter(\(x) "Z" %in% names(x), df)
```

As to why your method doesn't work, `for(i in 1:length(df))` iterates over each item in the original `length(df)`. As soon as `df[[i]] = NULL` happens once, then `df` is shorter than it was when the loop started, so the last iteration will be out of bounds. And you'll also skip some items: if `df[[2]]` is removed then the original `df[[3]]` is now `df[[2]]`, and the current `df[[3]]` was originally `df[[4]]`, so you hop over the original `df[[3]]` without checking it. Lesson: don't change the length of objects in the midst of iterating over them.

Answer (score 1):

Using `discard`:

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2)
purrr::discard(list_df, ~any(colnames(.x) == "Z"))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  A B
1 1 3
2 3 4
```

As you can see it removed the first dataframe which had column Z.

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2),
                  Z = c(1,4))

df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1,3),
                  B = c(3,4))
```